# Set different scaling for Flutter Windows Debug App

Tags: windows, flutter, flutter-layout

I was trying to create a flutter application for windows, and it really works really smooth and great as compared to running it inside the android emulator.
But my laptop currently has the scale property of 150%. I want to set scaling to 100% for the debug application, generated by flutter. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Have you considered overriding the text scale factor in MediaQuery?

Comment: Here, I am looking for scaling of the whole app, instead of just text. In laptops with smaller screens (i.e smaller than 15 inches), you can set scale parameter in windows to magnify the whole screen.